# Why Is Gray Matter Gray?

Tags: human-biology, brain, neurology

When I researched I found  different reason for this, the  popular
ones are

1) white matter is mylinated .this reason was given in reference books and   [this](https://www.livescience.com/32605-why-is-gray-matter-gray.html) website

while others say

2)cell body concentration causes grayish appearance ,as in brain the cell body is concentrated outside. As mentioned in [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-human-brain-have-gray-matter-on-the-outside-and-white-matter-on-the-inside-while-the-spinal-cord-has-the-reverse) .i.e cell body orientation.

also my teacher agrees with 2nd one, that the nissls granules contribute to the grayish appearance.orientation causes the effect of gray matter and white matter

I feel 1st reason to be more appropriate as there are billions of it couldn't be arranged as depicted in the second reason.

kindly help  me out to choose the accurate one, with appropriate reason of-course!

Comment: so whats is your question ? :) Just teasing you but kindly i higly doubt you will get anything more than just comment on it.

Comment: why is that true  ?

Comment: man i just say that this type of question is rather fit to the chat room rather posted like that. In my opinion SE its about sharing information not discuss like that. Still i hope that somebody try give you proper answer not jus opinion.

Comment: @L.Diago the question is clear and definitely answerable, you just might not be familiar with it if you haven't worked with gross specimens.

Comment: You are right that was the reason of my special interest to this question so thank you man. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The terms gray and white matter relate to their color in gross specimens (i.e., [not microscopic specimens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_pathology)) that have been formalin fixed. [Nissl granules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissl_body) describe a microscopic structure, the rough endoplasmic reticulum, and aren't directly related to the color of gross specimens. Here's an example of a frontal cross section from a University of Utah slide set:

[image]

You'll see it's generally a tannish-yellow (at least on my monitor, this image is a pretty good representation of what it looks like in person), but there are lighter "white" parts in the white matter areas, and darker "gray" parts in the cortex.

A live, or a [recently deceased](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHxyP-nUhUY) and not formalin fixed brain has different qualities, including color and consistency.

The color of the formalin fixed tissue is an artifact of the process of fixing, so it's not necessarily accurate to describe the gray color as something inherent to the cells in the gray matter, but generally yes, the whiter color in the white matter of formalin fixed brain is because of the high lipid concentration. The grayer color of the gray matter is because of the lower lipid concentration. This [lovely old JBC article from 1929](http://www.jbc.org/content/83/3/601.full.pdf) discusses some of these issues, mostly regarding white matter in response to staining after fixation, but also gray and white matter before staining.

Comment: Nice answer but i still dont see that answer to question what exacly makes gray matter gray ? :)

Comment: @L.Diago "the grayer color of the gray matter is because of the lower lipid concentration."

Comment: I know, actually i am trying to give you constructiv criticism. But the other part was about the fact what makes gray matter gray (i am not telling that your answer is bad but he put on tabel something about nissle substance )

Comment: @L.Diago can you please clarify your suggestion? I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: I think the criticism is a bit nitpicky. It's not like there is a "gray chemical compound" in gray matter. This answer provides the correct one: gray is the color of formalin-fixed brain tissue that contains less lipids than white matter. Unfixed brain tissue is not gray.

Comment: @BryanKrause I just tried to get him inculed something about the nissle substance. You know only to makes the answer perfect, but i know doesnt need to be included. But still i think he wanted oppinion about the nissle substance. Still wrote that i just teased him.

Comment: @L.Diago Nissl granules don't have much to do with it, but I've added it to the answer to clarify that.

Comment: @DeNovo I am sorry for that, but you know  this type of question can be usefull for anybody new in neurosciences so i wanted that to be perfect answer.

Comment: _The grayer color of the gray matter is because of the lower lipid concentration._ Is it known, why the lipid concentration differs between the inner outer parts of the brain?

Comment: @Marzipanherz [myelin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myelin)

Comment: so you are saying first answer is correct right? i.e white matter is mylinated , inturn mylin is made up of lipids. but the problem with that is mylin sheath is formed in between shwaan cell and axon how could you see the color of middle layer

Comment: @sudhanvab plasma membranes are not opaque. The intracellular contents of a tissue are typically what give that tissue a characteristic color.